# Android How can i make a gradient of this EditText

Tags: java, android, css, xml, graphics

This colour code is given to me:

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(53% 0% -90deg,rgb(255,255,255) 0%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%); 
background-image:linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(255,255,255) 0%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
width:787px;
height:142px;
border-color:rgb(221,221,221);
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
```

And ask for this [this is a preview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RHyHmdRczRM0N3anFMSVZkSjg/view?usp=sharing)
I try This code in my background of edittext

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffcccccc"
                android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
                android:type="linear"
                android:endColor="#ffcccccc"
                android:angle="90" />
      <stroke android:color="#ffdddddd"
            android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
```

Now I want same as picture but i cant get It.
How can i set this ?

Comment: I want only gradient.I cant give gradient like this in css code

Comment: Can anybody help me ?

Comment: in your EditText xml attribute set it like this android:background="@drawable/gradient" where gradient is gradient.xml file that you have defined

Comment: yes I have defined this but its does not give effect like in picture

Comment: I tried messing with code  try this <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffcccccc"
        android:type="linear"
        android:endColor="#fff5f5f6"
        android:angle="90" /> startColor is what shown on top and endColor is shown on bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the right code for getting gradient.

```
     <gradient android:startColor="#ffcccccc" 
android:type="linear"
  android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
 android:endColor="#fff5f5f6" 
android:angle="90" />
```